# Force browser to download file instead of opening it

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I would like to download http://foobar.com/song.mp3 as `song.mp3`, instead of having Chrome open it in its native `<audio>` player in the browser.

How can I accmplish this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to make sure to send these headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=song.mp3;
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

The `send_file` method does it for you:

```
get '/:file' do |file|
  file = File.join('/some/path', file)
  send_file(file, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => File.basename(file))
end
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it and a much better explanation than I was writing up.

Comment: Here are the [docs for `send_file`](http://sinatra.rubyforge.org/api/classes/Sinatra/Streaming.html#M000022).