# Export multiple Qlik sense object using a single export extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qliksense

How to export multiple object with single click, 
I need to export multiple excel files in a single click.

For Example, I have following 3 objects,

```
var objectid = ['abckd' , 'gffgjn', 'bvds'];
```

```js
$scope.exportExcelDeeper = function (object) {
  senseApp.getObject(object).then(function (model) {
    model.exportData().then(function (reply) {
        $window.location.href = "/saml" + reply;
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<button value="export" ng-click="exportExcelDeeper('abckd' , 'gffgjn', 'bvds')">Export</button>
```

I can export excel file if it is one. But how to I achieve if multiple object ids are there?

Can anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try some other approach. Instead of setting `window.location.href` generate multiple links and click them.

Here is a good example https://stackoverflow.com/a/39452091/3209523