# Download XLSX file created by XlsxWriter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to save an xlsx file to the browser downloads, the following functions gets activated when clicking a browser button

```
def trip_bit
@car = Car.find(params[:id])
@t = @car.trips.all
@trips = @t.order(:started_at)

if @trips then
  doc = XlsxWriter.new
  doc.quiet_booleans!
  sheet = doc.add_sheet("Vitácora de Viajes "+@car.model+' '+@car.year.to_s)
  sheet.freeze_top_left = 'A2'
  sheet.add_row(['Salida', 'Llegada', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'Distancia', 'Duración', 'Score'])
  @trips.each do |trip|
    sheet.add_row([trip.started_at.to_s, trip.finished_at.to_s, if trip.origin then trip.origin.address end, if trip.destination then trip.destination.address end, trip.distance.to_s+'km', trip.duration.to_s+'min', trip.grade])
  end
  sheet.add_row(["","","","Total", @trips.map { |trip| trip.distance }.sum.to_s+"km", @trips.map { |trip| trip.duration}.sum.to_s+"min", ""])
else
  redirect_to my_car_details_path
  flash.now[:alert] = 'Este coche no tiene viajes registrados'
end

send_file doc, :filename => "bitacora.xlsx"

end
```

The xlsx file `doc` gets created and saved to the local filesystem, but I can't find a way to send it to the browser downloads.

Comment: Do you mean that the file gets saved if someone clicks on it, but not in the "downloads" folder of the computer? Or that it doesn't show up in the list of downloads in the browser menu drop down? What browsers have you tested with?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868945/force-browser-to-download-file-instead-of-opening-it

Comment: I have tasted with Chrome and Safari, what I am trying to say is that the xlsx file exits, but I don't know how to send it to the browser downloads. With the send_file I get a red screen that says **no implicit conversion of XlsxWriter into String**

Comment: @Beartech I believe send_file does not work with XlsxWriter

Comment: Still unclear what you mean by: "I am trying to say is that the xlsx file exits, but I don't know how to send it to the browser downloads".

Comment: When working on local, I get to save the file in the root folder of my app with FileUtilities::mv, and It has all the data I requested, the problem is that I can't find a way to send it to the browser downloads when clicking the button

Comment: You say you think send_file doesn't work with XlsxWriter but you are using it. Have you tried changing that line to `send_file doc, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => "bitacora.xlsx"`

Comment: Yes, I put it there because I don't know what else to use, I have already tried your line and Im still getting the same error **No implicit conversion of XlsxWriter into String**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the docs for `send_file` and XlsxWriter, the error tells you that it is expecting a String but you are passing it an object of type XlsxWriter. You can try the `path` method to tell `sendfile` where the file is at...

```
send_file(doc.path, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename => "bitacora.xlsx", type: "application/xml")
```

You don't indicate any structure of your rails app so I'm assuming this is a controller method. You could probably do something along the lines of:

```
def trip_bit
@car = Car.find(params[:id])
@t = @car.trips.all
@trips = @t.order(:started_at)

if @trips then
  doc = XlsxWriter.new
  doc.quiet_booleans!
  sheet = doc.add_sheet("Vitácora de Viajes "+@car.model+' '+@car.year.to_s)
  sheet.freeze_top_left = 'A2'
  sheet.add_row(['Salida', 'Llegada', 'Origen', 'Destino', 'Distancia', 'Duración', 'Score'])
  @trips.each do |trip|
    sheet.add_row([trip.started_at.to_s, trip.finished_at.to_s, if trip.origin then trip.origin.address end, if trip.destination then trip.destination.address end, trip.distance.to_s+'km', trip.duration.to_s+'min', trip.grade])
  end
  sheet.add_row(["","","","Total", @trips.map { |trip| trip.distance }.sum.to_s+"km", @trips.map { |trip| trip.duration}.sum.to_s+"min", ""])
else
  redirect_to my_car_details_path
  flash.now[:alert] = 'Este coche no tiene viajes registrados'
end

respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx
  end

end
```

The code above is a straight up guess as XlsxWriter is a binding of a C library and the documentation from a Rails perspective is really thin and pretty much useless to me. I have been using the axlsx_rails gem. It allows you to define a template and just hand that template a Rails data structure. I highly encourage you to check it out at: https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails

It allows you to keep working in a Rails-ish way. When I want to export a spreadsheet of users to xlsx I just do this in my controller:

```
  def index
    @users = User.active
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xlsx
    end
  end
```

Then in my views alongside my `index.html.erb` I have a file called `index.xlsx.axlsx` that looks like:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Users") do |sheet|
sheet.add_row ['User', 'User Access Role']
  @users.each do |user|
    sheet.add_row [user.email, user.role.name]
  end
end
```

As you can see you have your logic for spreadsheet creation in the template. The way you are doing it is very hack-is and messy.

Comment: Thanks I am using the axlsx gem now and it works perfect!